# Automatically login into facebook with PHP via curl (?)

Tags: php, facebook, curl, authentication, autologin

I need to login into Facebook with my account because i want to create a crawler that fetchs some data from an app and put it into a database.

I don't know if it's possible and where to start, i just know that some facebook APIs exist, but the url i found as a reference [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com/) seems down.

I need to do this with a script PHP.

Can you give me an hint?

edit: now the reference url is up.

Comment: This would almost certainly violate the Facebook Terms of Service: "You will not collect users' content or information, or otherwise access Facebook, using automated means (such as harvesting bots, robots, spiders, or scrapers) without our permission." http://www.facebook.com/terms.php

Comment: Why don't you create your own application using legit facebook api to fetch the data you want ? You can easily schedule crawling tasks with graph api without being logged with offline_access tokens.

Comment: ok but then i need informations from another app.. can i?

Comment: which informations ? as each application have a page, you can from one app fetch posts/comments/photos/whatever from another app's page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'll say this is not the correct way to be using the Facebook API, and that the API docs aren't down (for me - try http://developers.facebook.com/docs/ )

But anyway if you insist, what you will need to do is:

1) Fetch the Facebook login page, collect any cookies and nonces

2) POST email/password + misc other form details + cookies to the form login url, then save cookies back

3) Fetch urls away with the cookies

Just use cURL to save the cookies to a file using

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies/'.session_id().'.txt'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies/'.session_id().'.txt');
```

and it should work.

Comment: now they are up for me too; thank you for the answer, would you suggest another method to do that task?

Comment: this works! now i have a more complicated step to catch! in another question i think..